# Expected result for correctly ordering list

Tags: probability

I'm unsure how to tackle or formulate this correctly, but i'll give it my best:

I have an array of 5 values. [1,2,3,4,5]

The array has exactly 1 correct order, which i do not know. If i get 1 point for each correctly ordered element in the set, what is my expected score by randomly sorting the array?

So for instance, let's say that [1,2,3,4,5] is the correct order. This would get me 5 points.

In this example [1,2,3,5,4] would get me 3 points, and [5,4,3,2,1] would get me 1 point.

Also, as a bonus question, would it be better to randomly order this array as opposed to selecting the same value 5 times? ( [1,1,1,1,1] would get me 1 point without any risks)

Am not so good with probabilities, so would appreciate the help :-)

Comment: There are many similar problems solved as examples in probability textbooks, often with different scenarios such as a secretary stuffing $n$ letters in $n$ addressed envelopes, or men getting their hats back from the cloakroom in random order, and the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the permutations are equally probable, then the chance of each number being put in the correct position (and thereby the expected score you get from that single number) is $\frac 1 n$. By the linearity of expectation, the expected total score is $n\cdot \frac 1 n =1$.

Comment: Ok so in essence it wouldn't matter what you would do. (Choose randomly or place the same number in every slot). I would have expected the answer to be a bit more complex, but since I really don't understand enough of the subject, I'll accept your answer :-) Does this problem have a specific name in probability? Would love to read up on it.

Comment: In fact as @Ross Millikan stated in his answer, it does matter which method we choose because the variance of the second method is lower (zero). For related references, you may want to search under "statistics of random permutations" or "fixed points of random permutations". These are however related to the case that repetitions are not allowed. But I thought it might be interesting to you that two random permutations agree in exactly one position in expectation.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the additional info!

Answer (score 1):

The expected number of points from $1$ is $\frac 15$, so by the linearity of expectation the expected total is $1$. The expectation is the same if you put the same number on every slot, but the variance is lower